# Node Express Server doesn't handle http redirects properly

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, server

I'm trying to use a combination of 2 Express servers to redirect users from http to https and also to redirect requests with www to non www, because cert requires non www. First problem, user visits https://www.example.com they get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Second problem, user visits http://www.example.com there is a DNS error. Users can only successfully visit http://example.com (and get redirected) and https://example.com. I have tried a few solutions but a lot of the examples for Express seem outdated, what needs to change to cover the above two use cases?

```
  // Create Express Server
  server = express();
  httpServer = express();

  // Redirect http to https
  httpServer.set('port', 80);

  httpServer.get("*", function (req, res, next) {
      res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + "/" + req.path);
  });

  http.createServer(httpServer).listen(80);


  server.set('trust proxy', true);

  // Add server static middleware
  server.use( st(options.prod.st) );

  server.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var str = "www.";
    if (req.headers.host.indexOf(str) === 0) {
      res.redirect(301, req.protocol + "://" + req.headers.host.slice(str.length) + req.originalUrl);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });

  // Fallback to /index.html
  server.use(fallback(prodRoot));

  // Start Server
  https.createServer(creds, server).listen(options.prod.port);
```

Comment: Default https port is 433 so u need to listen it.
To serve www.example.com you should create additional ns records.

If you need to redirect from https:// www.example.com you need a wildcard cert.

Comment: options.prod.port = 443. I will look into the wildcard cert and the ns record. TY

Comment: OK, added www ns record and now DNS is working for `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` BUT the second part of the question is still unresolved.`https://www.example.com` does not redirect to `https://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` does not redirect to `https://example.com`. The way I understand this, all I should need to do is setup redirects properly and wildcard cert won't be necessary.

Comment: OK, I did some debugging on the requests. The redirect isn't working because even when user visits `https://www.example.com`, `req.host` === `example.com` NOT `www.example.com`. Could this mean something is still wrong with the NS records?

Comment: req.host is a part of current request URL which indicates hostname. NS is not involved here. `https://test.example.com` host would be `test.example.com`

Comment: The comment was `req.host` resolves to `example.com` when user is making a request to `www.example.com` so there is no way to check ` if (req.host.indexOf("www.") === 0)`

Comment: Im guessing there is a recent change in express so that the middleware in the above code snippet no longer works?

Comment: Do you have any kind of proxy?

`req.host` is a legacy alias for http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.hostname and should return Host from headers (with www.)

Comment: here is a tested express app which redirects every request with wrong host https://gist.github.com/claritypotion/de3d23d00d26f03f05d7 if it won't work with your setup you are probably using some proxy which rewrites or adds headers (though this still won't help you with https warnings)

Comment: `req.hostname` still ONLY resolves to `example.com` when requesting `www.example.com`. I will try your last suggestion shortly.

Comment: OK, now everything is up and running. I ended up taking your suggestion @Fella and used a similar approach to store the hostname in a variable and use it to check against the hostname of the request. Redirect to work for every endpoint except the root, but the app is displaying fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a NS record for www, most issues were resolved. Thanks @Fella for the suggestions. Corrected code is below. I ended up also having to fix an issue if user lands on `https://www.example.com` I needed to add a CORS policy to prevent mixed content warnings on some XMLHttpRequests in the web app. I also remove the redirect from www to non-www, it just isn't necessary after fixing NS records.

```
 // Create Connect Server
  server = express();
  httpServer = express();

  // Redirect http to https

  httpServer.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
      res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.headers.host + req.path);
  });

  http.createServer(httpServer).listen(80);

  // Add serve static middleware
  server.use( st(options.prod.st) );

  // Implement CORS policy
  server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });

  // Fallback to /index.html
  server.use(fallback(prodRoot));

  // Start Server
  https.createServer(creds, server).listen(443);
```